# Undefined variable: result in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get to data from database details from model to controller i was not get 
it's saying Undefined variable: result   can any one know how to get data from model to controller?

controller.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    public function setting()
    {

       $this->load->database();
       session_start();
       $userss="";
       if($_SESSION["registerid"])
       {
           $userss = $_SESSION["registerid"];
       }
       $this->load->model('setting_model');

       $this->setting_model->getsetting($userss);    

       $data12345 = array(
          'registerid'     => $result[0]->registerid,
           'username'      => $result[1]->username,
           'email'         => $result[2]->email,
           'password'      => $result[3]->password,
           'companyname'   => $result[0]->companyname,
           'phonenumber'   => $result[0]->phonenumber   ,
           'address'       => $result[0]->address,
           'postalcode'    => $result[0]->postalcode,
           'descriptionofcompany' =>$result[0]->descriptionofcompany,
          'creditcardinformation' =>$result[0]->creditcardinformation,
          'title'=>'Setting Page'

);

        //passing page title 
        $this->load->helper('url');  // passing base url 
        $this->load->view('setting',$data12345);   // passing setting.php view

    }   
}
```

setting_model.php

```
<?php
class setting_model extends CI_Model{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getsetting($userss) {

         $this->load->database();
         $condition = "username =" . "'" .  $userss . "'";
         $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->from('register');
         $this->db->where($condition);
         $this->db->limit(1);
         $query = $this->db->get();

         if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
             return $query->result();
         } else {
             return false;
         }
    }

// Read data from database to show data in admin page    
}//end class

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to assign the query result to the $result variable. Try this `$result = $this->setting_model->getsetting($userss);` in the controller.

Comment: i used different query i got the result using $this->db->get();